# Itertools: `for a in b: for c in b`

Tags: python, nested-loops

I was just looking through the `itertools` documentation, looking for a way to get rid of a nested for loop like this:

```
for a in b:
    for c in b:
        <statement>
```

However, I couldn't find anything. Is there not a function for this? Should I just keep the nested loops?

Comment: `for a, c in itertools.product(b, repeat=2): …`

Comment: or `itertools.product(b, repeat=2)`.

Comment: The original question seems to have been using `for c in b:` in the second line.  Several answers seem to apply to that.  Maybe if a change of the question changes its meaning so drastically, SO should implement a way of handling this.

Comment: Rolled back to the original version as it changes the meaning of the question drastically http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/106812/235416

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is. Its called [itertools.product](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

For example:

```
import itertools

for item in itertools.product([0, 1], repeat = 2):
    print item
```

**Output**

```
(0, 0)
(0, 1)
(1, 0)
(1, 1)
```

It is equivalent to

```
b = [0, 1]
for a in b:
    for c in b:
        print (a, c)
```

Comment: Before anyone downvotes this answer, please note that the question was changed! This answer solved the original question correctly.

Comment: @wheaties Thanks man :) But I have to remove this answer now :'(

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`chain.from iterable`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
from itertools import chain

b = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]

for i in chain.from_iterable(b):
    print i
```

Ideally, `b` has all the values. So this translates to:

```
for a in b:
    for c in a:
        print c
```

Working [example](http://ideone.com/ItmVFj). What you're really trying to do is *flatten* a list, and thats actually included in the [recipes for `itertools`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes).

Comment: Great answer, was about to post this :)

Comment: @GamesBrainiac You rock :)

Comment: @GamesBrainiac Please note that I rolled back to the original version as it changes the meaning of the question drastically as per this answer meta.stackoverflow.com/a/106812/235416

Comment: @thefourtheye Thats fine. I'd never downvote any of your questions unless someone threatened me to :P

Comment: @GamesBrainiac Neither do I :) I ll just mention if there is something wrong.